# How to make type-annotation-only type assertions?

Tags: python, python-3.x, mypy, python-typing

I have two functions:

```
def get_foo(params) -> Optional[str]
def bar(foo: str)
```

And a function which chains these functions together:

```
def f(params):
    # other stuff up here
    foo = get_foo(params)
    return bar(foo)
```

I know based on the other things happening in my function that the result of `get_foo` will *never* be None.

When I run `mypy` against this file, I of course get errors:

```
error: Argument 1 of "bar" has incompatible type "Optional[str]"; expected "str"
```

which makes sense.

I could add an `assert foo is not None` statement, but this is hot-path code and in my tests it has measurable performance impact. **I would like to make a type assertion for mypy only**. How do I do that?

EDIT: I also tried adding a comment `#type: str` after the assignment statement, but this generated a similar error

Comment: A note: If you run Python with the `-O` option ("optimize"), it will remove the `assert`s at compile time, so it has no runtime penalty. Only other change it makes is to make `__debug__` a constant meaning `False` instead of `True`, so most code should run unchanged aside from the `assert`s.

Comment: How about `foo: str = get_foo(params)`. You might be forced to ignore MyPy error with `# type: ignore` as `get_foo` return `Optional[str]`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You're not going to be happy about this. The officially designed way to assert to static type checkers that a value has a specific type is [`typing.cast`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.cast), which is an actual function with a real runtime cost, I believe *more* expensive than the `assert` you want to replace. It just returns its second argument unchanged, but it's still got function call overhead. Python's type annotation system is not designed with a zero-overhead type assertion syntax.

As an alternative, you could use `Any` as an "escape hatch". If you annotate `foo` with type `Any`, mypy should allow the `bar` call. Local variable annotations have no runtime cost, so the only runtime cost is an extra local variable store and lookup:

```
from typing import Any

def f(params):
    foo: Any = get_foo(params)
    return bar(foo)
```

Aside from that, your best option may be to use the `assert` and run Python with the `-O` flag, which disables asserts.

Comment: Thanks, really appreciate the answer and I marked it as accepted. However, this does feel like a missing feature from mypy. In contrast, TypeScript allows [manually narrowing types through type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions). However in the example above if you change `Any` to `str`, this will generate an error.

Comment: "... typing.cast, which is an actual function with a real runtime cost, I believe more expensive than the assert you want to replace..."

This is not true. Per [doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.cast), "but at runtime we intentionally don’t check anything (we want this to be as fast as possible)."

Comment: @KFL While ``cast`` doesn't do anything, it is still a function that needs to be looked up and called. Function calls, even of identity functions, are *not* free in Python.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `TYPE_CHECKING` variable that is `False` during runtime but `True` during type checking. This would avoid performance hit of `assert`:

```py
from typing import TYPE_CHECKING

def f(params):
    # other stuff up here
    foo = get_foo(params)
    
    if TYPE_CHECKING:
        assert foo is not None
    
    return bar(foo)
```

Comment: That's still got a performance impact - you've got to look up a global variable and branch on it, both of which are much more expensive operations in Python than someone might expect if they're used to languages like C.

Answer (score 0):

If you use [pytype](https://github.com/google/pytype) as your type checker, the following works:

```
def f(params):
    # other stuff up here
    foo = get_foo(params)  # type: str  # pytype: disable=annotation-type-mismatch
    return bar(foo)
```

Agreed, it's not pretty, but I believe that's exactly what you need (and to be fair, what you are trying to do is not pretty either).

EDIT: As mentioned, this works with pytype, not mypy.

Comment: This unfortunately doesn't pass type checking. Mypy emits the error `Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "Optional[str]", variable has type "str") `. FWIW, the OP mentioned that this doesn't work in the question.

Comment: Ah indeed, I missed this was with mypy. I'm using pytype and this works with it. It's likely there is an equivalent to disable=annotation-type-mismatch though.
Note that in the OP, they didn't add " # pytype: disable=annotation-type-mismatch"

Comment: I think this would also work in mypy if you added `# type: ignore[assignment]`

Answer (score 0):

You can explicitly annotate `foo` with the narrowed type `str`:

```
foo: str = get_foo(params)
```

Ordinarily, this would cause mypy to emit the error

```
error: Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "str | None", variable has type "str")  [assignment]
```

However, you can silence this lint by adding [`# type: ignore` comment](https://peps.python.org/pep-0484/#type-comments) to the assignment line:

```
foo: str = get_foo(params)  # type: ignore
```

Optionally, you can narrow the scope of the lint suppression as `# type: ignore [assignment]`.

All code that follows will be validated under the assumption that `foo` is a `str`.