# Type hints for dict when finding min value

Tags: python, type-hinting, mypy

The following code, which finds the minimum value of a dict based on its keys:

```
from typing import Dict

a: Dict[str, float] = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}
min(a, key=a.get)
```

raises the mypy error:

```
Value of type variable "SupportsLessThanT" of "min" cannot be "Optional[float]"
```

which seems to indicate that the types defined in `Dict` are `Optional`. How can I make the code above pass the mypy test? I've tried a check to ensure that none of the values are `None`, but that does not work:

```
# Does not work
if any([x is None for x in a.values()]):
    raise ValueError('foo')
else:
    min(a, key=a.get)
```

How can I make this code pass the mypy test with the bare minimum of code?

Comment: `dict.get` can possibly return `None`, if the key is not present. In your case it won't, but the *types* don't know that. You could use e.g. `key=lambda k: d[k]`.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/57931661/3001761

Comment: @jonrsharpe Ah, yes, of course. I'm embarrassed I missed that. That is the answer I was looking for. If you make it an answer I can select it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason MyPy is unhappy is that, as a `Mapping`, a dictionary's `get` method returns an *optional* of the value type when called with a single argument. E.g. see [the typeshed definition](https://github.com/python/typeshed/blob/1d1d35c87af28cec08d049561c3baf13532f98d4/stdlib/typing.pyi#L422-L431):

```
class Mapping(_Collection[_KT], Generic[_KT, _VT_co]):
    # ...
    @overload
    def get(self, key: _KT) -> Optional[_VT_co]: ...
    @overload
    def get(self, key: _KT, default: Union[_VT_co, _T]) -> Union[_VT_co, _T]: ...
```

In the absence of the `default` value, `get` *can* return `None` if the key isn't present in the dictionary. In your case that will never happen, because you're always using keys that *are* present, but the *types* don't know that!

Unfortunately, per e.g. [How to make type-annotation-only type assertions?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57931661/3001761), it's quite awkward to assert the type of a value in Python. You could effectively erase the type by assigning the method to an `Any`-typed variable:

```
getter: Any = a.get
min(a, key=getter)
```

but that doesn't seem very safe. Another option is to use an implementation that invokes `__getitem__`, which always returns the value type (`__getitem__(self, k: _KT) -> _VT_co` from the same source as above):

```
min(a, key=lambda k: a[k])
```